# Added new WordPress site on GCP with Marketplace. Publishing fails. Link cloaker fails

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

In Launching WordPress installation, in GCP, I cannot post with the error "publishing failed.". I tried both without updating and with updating to WP 5.4.1. I am having a hell of a time deploying WordPress in GCP. The permalinks don't work and I change the timezone, i am guessing or set the Site URL to vetsforweed.net and updated the A record at my Namecheap DNS to the external ip. sometimes the site locks up and I have to delete the vm instance and redploy. I have installed WordPress at least 10 times trying to get a working installation.

I switched to the classic Editor, I am able to publish. the post uses the permalinks setting of Post name: and it tells me the post link is : http://34.73.194.87/petition for a post titled "Petition" and I get a 404 Not found. I had done Settings...Permalinks to Post name:. I am so stuck!

What a nightmare! I cannot get anything to work with WordPress 5.4.1, no posts show up with a permalink. I cannot even click the date to see the post. It does show up in the list of Posts. Argg!

Is WordPress 5.4.1 known to be broken? What can I do to get a WordPress site up and running well? I appreciate you for your assistance.

Comment: Hi Robert! I will need more information to help you. Are you using Bitnami Wordpress or Click to Deploy Wordpress?

Comment: I'm asking you this so I can reproduce an environment like yours and see what may be misconfigured.

Comment: Clcik to Deploy.

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?id=00a8bad7-693b-4911-9f10-7bef620bdd13&project=callistohouse&folder&organizationId&supportedpurview=project

Comment: It doesn't sound like you do, but do you have any plugins or themes installed, or is this just the basic WordPress installation that is being difficult. Are there any errors in your error logs?

Comment: Make sure your file permissions are not to strict. You could try starting with 775 for folders and 664 for files. Try deploying a LAMP stack, and then install WordPress manually -- https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress. It's super simple to install it manually.

Comment: I just tried again. After I load the click-to-deploy, I delete the Akismet Spam and the Hello Dolly plugins. Then I update the WordPress version to 5.4.1, then update the three themes. Then I go to Settings...General and update the SiteURL and WordPressURL both to http://callistohouse.club. I also goto Namecheap and update the DNS A record with the new external IP that I had just changed. When I Save Changes it locks up.

Comment: A) where could I find error logs? Alright, I need to reinstall to set flag and generate debug.log. I am Deploying " New WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic deployment
" for a change, And following this: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-set-up-wordpress-error-logs-in-wp-config/
B) following this: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp

Comment: I got lost on SSH. Do I need to setmy publik key on the server? The Bitnami WordPress did not put files under /var/www/html/...I am lost now.

Comment: I am sticking and proceeding with WordPress certified by Bitnami. I am removing the LAMP install that was confusing me.

How can I change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)?

Comment: This seems to be working, as I need.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to loading WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic and this worked, completely. So far. Now I have to import a WP export that is 136MB. Firs, I will deploy WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic there.

Thanks for assistance.